# Could anyone tell me a better solution for this problem? I could only think of brute force way which is O(n^2)

Tags: algorithm, optimization, time-complexity

Recently I was attempting the following problem:

```
Given an array of integers, arr. 
Find sum of floor of (arr[i]/arr[j]) for all pairs of indices (i,j).
```

e.g.

```
Input: arr[]={1,2,3,4,5} 
Output: Sum=27.
```

Explanation:

```
(1/1)+(1/5)+(1/4)+(1/2)+(1/3) = 1+0+0+0+0 = 1

(5/1)+(5/5)+(5/4)+(5/2)+(5/3) = 5+1+1+2+1 = 10

(4/1)+(4/5)+(4/4)+(4/2)+(4/3) = 4+0+1+2+1 = 8

(2/1)+(2/5)+(2/4)+(2/2)+(2/3) = 2+0+0+1+0 = 3

(3/1)+(3/5)+(3/4)+(3/2)+(3/3) = 3+0+0+1+1 = 5
```

I could only think of naive O(n^2) solution. Is there any other better approach?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not giving you the solution, only a hint: if all the elements are sorted from smallest to largest, wouldn't a triangle of your 25 floored fractions be 0? Since you know it's 0, would you have to actually compute it or could you find a way to skip those fractions?

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire what is 'triangle of 25 floored fractions'?

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire: that doesn't improve the asymptotic complexity, it is a mere x2 improvement.

Comment: @YvesDaoust The OP says he could only think of a "naive O(n^2) solution" and ask for a better approach. I gave him a faster, non-naive O(n^2) hint.

Comment: Do you really need a more efficient solution?

Comment: Also, this probably should be better asked on codereview, now that I think about it.

Comment: Without code, that's not suitable for review, I believe. But do check out the guidelines over there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possibility resides in "quickly" skipping the elements that are the same integer multiple of a given element (after rounding).

For the given example, the vertical bars below delimit runs of equal ratios (the lower triangle is all zeroes and ignored; I show the elements on the left and the ratios on the right):

```
1 -> 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 ≡ 2 | 3 | 4 | 5
2 ->     3 | 4   5 ≡     1 | 2   2
3 ->         4   5 ≡         1   1
4 ->             5 ≡             1
```

For bigger arrays, the constant runs can be longer.

So the algorithm principle is

- sort all elements increasingly;
- process the elements from smallest to largest;

  - for a given element, find the index of the first double and count the number of skipped elements;
  - from there, find the index of the first triple and count twice the number of skipped elements;
  - continue with higher multiples until you exhaust the tail of the array.

A critical operation is to "find the next multiple". This should be done by an *exponential search* followed by a *dichotomic search*, so that the number of operations remains logarithmic in the number of elements to skip (a pure dichotomic search would be logarithmic in the total number of remaining elements). Hence the cost of a search will be proportional to the sum of the logarithms of the distances between the multiples.

Hopefully, this sum will be smaller than the sum of the distances themselves, though in the worst case the complexity remains `O(N)`. In the best case, `O(log(N))`.

A global analysis is difficult and in theory the worst-case complexity remains `O(N²)`; but in practice it could go down to `O(N log N)`, because the worst case would require that the elements grow faster than a geometric progression of common ratio 2.

---

**Addendum:**

If the array contains numerous repeated values, it can be beneficial to compress it by storing a repetition count and a single instance of every value. This can be done after sorting.

Comment: sorting itself have average `O(n Log n)` complexity.

Comment: @SushantYelpale: and ?

Answer (score 0):

```
int[] arr = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

int result = 0;
int BuffSize = arr.Max() * 2;
int[] b = new int[BuffSize + 1];
int[] count = new int[BuffSize];

for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; ++i)
    count[arr[i]]++;

for (int i = BuffSize - 1; i >= 1; i--)
{
    b[i] = b[i + 1] + count[i];
}

for (int i = 1; i < BuffSize; i++)
{
    if (count[i] == 0)
    {
        continue;
    }
    for (int j = i, mul = 1; j < BuffSize; j += i, mul++)
    {
        result += 1 * (b[j] - b[Math.Min(BuffSize - 1, j + i)]) * mul * count[i];
    }
}
```

This code takes advantage of knowing difference between each successive value ahead of time, and only process the remaining portion of the array rather than redundantly processing the entire thing n^2 times, 
I believe it has a worst case runtime of O(n*sqrt(n)*log(n))

Comment: What if the values are { 1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000 } ?

Comment: I believe it still gives the correct answer of 12345. Probably uses a lot of ram though. Runtime is still less than O(n^2)

Comment: The major problem is that it explodes the complexity. 10000 < 5² doesn't seem realistic.

Comment: I see your point. This is probably not particularly useful for an arbitrary set of data.

Comment: In fact, you turned the complexity to O(M + f(N)) where M is the largest value in the array. Just clearing the counts (which you forgot to do) can have an unbearable cost.

Comment: This algorithm is definitely not useful for large values of m. I don't know what the etiquette here is, but should I remove the answer? I don't want to lead anyone astray. Just out of curiosity, where does the count array need to be cleared. in C# it's initialized to 0 anyway?

Comment: Ok, maybe the arrays are implicitly cleared, I didn't know. But this still costs O(M). You can leave your answer, but can you explain the method ?

Comment: Assuming a large number of elements, with relatively small magnitudes, the same result is yielded by skipping the elements which will yield an addition to the sum of zero. The solution is also not elegant as there is a fair bit of hackery to do with an off-by-one in the intermediate array b[]